# How to open a .bat file from another in a certain situation

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

So I am using the following code:

```
:begin 
SET /P runscript= [Question Here]
if %runscript%==:100 goto run blahblah.bat
if %runscript%==EXIT goto :A
pause
```

I am trying to make there be an option to open another .bat file in a different window, but when I answer :100, command prompt just shuts down. I am trying to be as clear as possible as to what I am trying to do, but this is just a snip of a very big project I am working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try start cmd /k to run the bat in new window. For goto, notice no colon before A. Lastly, your set command as written will include the space. I closed it here.

```
:begin 
   SET /P runscript=[Question Here]
   if %runscript%==:100 start cmd /k blahblah.bat
   if %runscript%==EXIT goto A
   pause
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if %runscript%==:100 goto run blahblah.bat
```

will attempt to find the label `run` on entry of `:100`

If you want to transfer execution to the batch `blahblah.bat` then remove the `goto run`

Comment: Dentist mode... try `if %runscript%==:100 echo 100found&pause` - see what happens then.

Comment: Yes, it displayed found&pause

Comment: In that case, `if %runscript%==:100 blahblah.bat` *should* execute blahblah.bat. Try `if %runscript%==:100 blahblah.bat&pause` which may yield a message that `blahblah.bat` is not recognised... if so, either install `blahblah.bat` in your `path` or specify the absolute path to `blahblah.bat` thus: `if %runscript%==:100 "c:\path\to\blahblah.bat"&pause` - and include the quotes (although they're only necessary if the path or batchname contain separators like spaces.) The `pause` is then only there for truly-spectacular failures, the target batch should take over control of the `cmd` session.